# Installing 32-bit Software Outside %windir%\Program Files (x86) on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: 64-bit, installation, windows-server-2008

I have a 32-bit app that I need to install and test on a Windows 2008 R2 server. This app has some dependencies on 3rd party 32-bit software (Oracle 10g client and TCL runtime -- a large portion of the app is TCL scripts). This app also creates Windows services to run.

The current version of the product requires that its binaries (`.exe`s and `.dll`s) and scripts be installed to `D:\App`. This path is hard-coded in the scripts and config files. It also requires that the TCL runtime be installed to `D:\TCL`.

I'm concerned that if I try to install 32-bit binaries outside of `%windir%\Program Files (x86)`, then weird things will happen; are my concerns warranted? Are there any side effects or issues with running 32-bit apps outside of `%windir%\Program Files (x86)` on Windows 2008 R2? Does our app have to do anything special with the binaries if they're running outside the `%windir%\Program Files (x86)` folder?

Comment: This should probably be closed, as the least appropriate forum of the three it's posted to.

Comment: And yet, it's the only one that's received any responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows detects the 32/64-bitness from the executable, so in theory a 32-bit binary can be installed anywhere.

The reason for the two Program Files directories is mainly to eliminate the risk of having both 32-bit and 64-bit installs of the same program present, and their installation files creating conflicts and/or performance problems.

However, the issue is unclear enough so that all I can say is that it also depends on what the installation jobs do exactly. Oracle installation is especially large and complex. While I believe that this has a chance of working out, still anything can happen. You will just have to try and see (use a virtual machine if you don't want to destroy your server).

You will have some issues with IIS if you try to run 32-bit extensions on 64-bit IIS.
See also [Running 32-bit Applications on 64-bit Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee52acd2-84e0-417c-92b3-80b1cb384828.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have an app which makes use of Oracle Client and .net framework, in addition to few custom dll files, which I've installed on d:\app folder for a good 3 weeks now, and I've been monitoring it daily (it's an in-house app) - haven't noticed any weirdness. My app also creates few services, and it's been running fine without any hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

So many bad things in this app - installing to a hard-coded location, multiple services, hard-coded config paths, requiring a dependency to use a non-standard install.  Time to do some re-design, I think.